# How to fix responsive website to not let user scroll horizontally

Tags: css, web, media

I have designed a responsive website but whenever I view the site when the display width is smaller than 510px wide eg. iPhone or shrinked browser the content works as it should and compresses to the width of the browser but there is a big white space to the right and the user and scroll horizontally.

I find this unusual as there is no media queries for 510px width, just 390px, 700px, 850px, 906px and 960px.  Below is a screenshot of what is happening.

[image: screenshot]

Thanks.

Comment: @web-tiki Where can I upload the site's root folder for code inspection?

Comment: @user3479267 You can create a fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FX7cW/ theres the fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `width:500px;` on `<h1>` elements.

see this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/FX7cW/3/)**